# Why does this code to solve 3sum problem not work for cases for example [0, 0, 0]?

Tags: python, algorithm

Public code: https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/

For nums = [0,0,0] I get an empty list: [] when the solution should be a triplet of zeros.

```
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        n = len(nums)
        nums.sort()
        result = []
        h = {}
        for i in range(n):
            target = -nums[i]
            high, low = n-1, i + 1
            while low <= high:
                while low < high and nums[low] == nums[low + 1]:
                    low+=1 
                while low < high and nums[high-1] == nums[high]:
                    high-=1
                if target > nums[low] + nums[high]:
                    low+=1 
                elif target < nums[low] + nums[high]:
                    high-=1 
                elif target == nums[low] + nums[high]:
                    if low != high and high != i and low != i:
                        result.append([-target, nums[low], nums[high]])
                    low+=1
        new = []
        for item in result:
            if item not in new:
                new.append(item)
        return new
```

I can't figure out where exactly my logic is flawed. I added code at the end to deduplicate the final result list and I check if high = low before adding a tuple to results but something is off it looks like without the if low != high and high != i and low != i statement I also get triples that shouldn't be there because individual elements are duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by the following code block:

```
            while low < high and nums[low] == nums[low + 1]:
                low+=1 
            while low < high and nums[high-1] == nums[high]:
                high-=1
```

This is happening too early. By doing this, you may have `low` and `high` become equal and thereby miss a solution.

The fix is simple: perform this code block only *after* you have identified a solution. So without changing anything else, it already works by this move:

```
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        n = len(nums)
        nums.sort()
        result = []
        h = {}
        for i in range(n):
            target = -nums[i]
            high, low = n-1, i + 1
            while low <= high:
                # code moved away from this spot...
                # 
                if target > nums[low] + nums[high]:
                    low+=1 
                elif target < nums[low] + nums[high]:
                    high-=1 
                elif target == nums[low] + nums[high]:
                    if low != high and high != i and low != i:
                        result.append([-target, nums[low], nums[high]])
                    # ...and inserted here:
                    while low < high and nums[low] == nums[low + 1]:
                        low+=1 
                    while low < high and nums[high-1] == nums[high]:
                        high-=1
                    #
                    low+=1
        new = []
        for item in result:
            if item not in new:
                new.append(item)
        return new
```

## Other remarks

The above will work fine, but:

- The outer `while` loop could already exit when `low == high`, so change the `while` loop condition to `while low < high`
- ...and then you can also remove the following guard:

  ```
  if low != high and high != i and low != i
  ```

  ...because now that condition is guaranteed to be true when executed.
- The `elif target == nums[low] + nums[high]` can just be an `else:` as that condition is always going to be true when execution gets there.
- The `for` loop can stop 2 units earlier, since there must be room for distinct `low` and `high` indices
- The population of the `new` list (in order to remove duplicates) is inefficient. You can better avoid the creation of duplicates by making sure you skip `i` values in the `for i` loop when `nums[i]` turns out to be equal to `nums[i-1]`.

With those changes, we get this:

```
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        n = len(nums)
        nums.sort()
        result = []
        for i in range(n-2):
            if i and nums[i] == nums[i-1]:
                continue
            target = -nums[i]
            high, low = n-1, i + 1
            while low < high:
                if target > nums[low] + nums[high]:
                    low+=1 
                elif target < nums[low] + nums[high]:
                    high-=1 
                else:
                    result.append([-target, nums[low], nums[high]])
                    while low < high and nums[low] == nums[low + 1]:
                        low+=1 
                    while low < high and nums[high-1] == nums[high]:
                        high-=1
                    low+=1
        return result
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of trying to de-duplicate at the end of the function, rather use sets as you analyse the data.

Something like this:

```
def threeSum(nums):
    res = set()
    p = None
    for i, v in enumerate((_nums := sorted(nums))[:-2]):
        if p != v:
            p = v
            ds = set()
            for x in _nums[i+1:]:
                if x not in ds:
                    ds.add(-v-x)
                else:
                    res.add((v, -v-x, x))
    return list(map(list, res))
```